# Returning a Doctrine "find()" result as a class

Tags: doctrine-orm

So, I know that the result of a Doctrine "find()" (Doctrine 2) call results in a Doctrine-based class, but I'm trying to output just the relevant data back over a SOAP connection (don't ask) and don't want all of the Doctrine metadata to come through too.

For example, my result of a find('Account',1) gives me a class back with properties on it for firstName, lastName, and emailAddress. A property on the class also relates to the Hardware model and lets me tap into the associated results there. What I want to be returned, though, is something like:

```
object(stdClass)#15 (5) {
  ["companyName"]=>
  string(12) "test company"
  ["firstName"]=>
  string(5) "chris"
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["lastName"]=>
  string(7) "smith"
  ["hardware"]=> array(
    [0] => object(stdClass)#15 (5) {
        ["hostname"]=>
        string(12) "host1",
    [1] => object(stdClass)#16 (5) {
        ["hostname"]=>
        string(12) "host2",
    [2] => object(stdClass)#17 (5) {
        ["hostname"]=>
        string(12) "host3"
  )
```

It seems like there should be an automatic way to do this sort of thing so I don't have to write a custom filtering method/class just to strip out the data I need. Any tips from Doctrine devs out there?

Comment: So you don't want Doctrine to return a proxy instance?

Comment: hmm, i'm still new to Doctrine so I'm not 100% sure on the answer to that - but I'm going to say "correct".

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be something you are looking for:

```
$em->getRepository('namespace\entity')->createQueryBuilder('a')->where('criteria = 1')->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

But you need to modify the where.

Comment: Hmm, that sure seems like a lot of work - plus I don't want it as an array.

Comment: Hmm, I finally got back to trying this out...doesn't seem to work for me: `code` $hw = $em->getRepository('Account')->createQueryBuilder('a')->where('id = 1')->getQuery()->getArrayResult(); `code`

Answer (score 1):

Try to unwrap the related object:

```
$account->setHardware($account->getHardware()->toArray());
```

But forget the standard class thing, the only way to get it is to convert your objects to an array and then cast them to objects. Anyway, if it's a SOAP connection, I suppose you should use arrays instead of objects.